# How to write a test which should not find a test id in React Testing Library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

There is a situation when some test ids should not be present in the DOM and it must be tested.

For example:

```
describe('MyModal', () => {
  const testIds = [
    'first-test',
    'second-test',
    'third-test'
  ];

  it('should not render MyModal', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = renderWithClientInstance(
      <MyModal open={false} } />
    );
    testIds.forEach((testId) => expect(getByTestId(testId)).not.toBeInTheDocument());
  });
});
```

But this test fails with the following error message:

> TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by:
> [data-testid="first-test"]

How should it be written in order to check if those test ids aren't in the DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use `queryByTestId` instead of `getByTestId` because it doesn't fail when the queried element doesn't exist, instead, it returns either a value or `null`.

```
describe('MyModal', () => {
  const testIds = [
    'first-test',
    'second-test',
    'third-test'
  ];

  it('should not queryByTestId MyModal', () => {
    const { queryByTestId } = renderWithClientInstance(
      <MyModal open={false} } />
    );
    testIds.forEach((testId) => expect(queryByTestId(testId)).toBeNull());
  });
});
```